# Cannot upload picture from hard drive to eBay sandbox with API

Tags: c#, soap, ebay-api

I tried to upload my picture but it didn't work. I know sandbox doesn't support photos but I mean inside the sandbox listing there is main photo. Other sellers have a main photo so there must be a way.

My code compiles without an error but there just isn't a photo when I go to the sandbox. Here is the code I'm using:

```
apiCall.PictureFileList = new StringCollection();
apiCall.PictureFileList.Add(@"C:\Users\Danny\Desktop\deleteMeBiggerEbayPic.jpg");
item.PictureDetails = new PictureDetailsType();
item.PictureDetails.GalleryType = GalleryTypeCodeType.Gallery;
```

Comment: Is this all your code?! Also you mention it doesn't work in the sandbox.. Are you sure it is possible, maybe you should check with eBay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try the original code again and to my surprise it worked. Maybe I did something wrong but I cant be bothered checking, its working now. 
Here is the code:

```
            //Set the Picture Server URL for Sandbox 
            apiContext.EPSServerUrl = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll";
            //For production use this URL 
            //context.EPSServerUrl = "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll"; 


            //Set file path of the picture on the local disk  
            apiCall.PictureFileList = new StringCollection();

            apiCall.PictureFileList.Add(@"C:\Users\Danny\Desktop\MyGalleryPicOnHardDrive.jpg");

            //To specify a Gallery Image 
            item.PictureDetails = new PictureDetailsType();
            //The first picture is used for Gallery URL 
            item.PictureDetails.GalleryType = GalleryTypeCodeType.Gallery;

            //To add more pictures 
            //apiCall.PictureFileList.Add(@"C:\TEMP\pic2.gif");
```

Comment: New eBay documentation is good for uploading variation pictures form the hard drive:
https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2196/kw/Upload%20pictures%20.Net%20SDK

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can't upload pictures from your local hard-drive using the eBay SOAP API. You need to sepcify a public URL where eBay can download the image from.

BTW: The sandbox supports photos, the only thing it doesn't support are gallery images.

Comment: sorry I didn't mention this but I got the code off the ebay website, surely it should work?
https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/320/~/options-for-adding-pictures-to-an-item
I need to resize the image before listing it so I'm not sure if I can use the UploadSiteHostedPictures code?